# acess token for getting nearby places

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am developing phonegap application and I want to show a list for nearby places using facebook. 
I understand that I need to get access_token in order to use the graph api, but it seems akward and strange to ask the user login to facebook so I can get list of places that has nothing with you (I am not looking for places the user like/visited).

There is another way without asking the user to log-in?

Comment: Can I generate access token for my application fake user name and use it for all users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get places with an [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/), which does not require the user to log in.

Good luck with this. Location search with the Facebook APIs is challenging.

You might want to take a look at the [Factual API](http://developer.factual.com/) or one of the Mapping APIs to get the place data.

Comment: thanks a lot , it fixes my struggling, about the Factual API, I will look at it, I just need simple api to get all nearby common places. Thanks :)